# Validate form before sending ajax submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

Edit: So to clarify, this is inside of a bootstrap modal and the button's in the footer OUTSIDE of the form. I can't do a normal form submit because I'd have to change the location of the submit button to be inside of the form and I don't want to do that- it needs to stay inside the footer.

I'm trying to check to make sure required fields are filled out before submitting a form via ajax but all the answers I've come across say that I ought to use the jquery .validate() plugin and I don't want to use any additional plugins. Is this possible to do?

HTML:

```
<form id="event-form">
        <div class='row'>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                <label class="form-label" for="event[title]">Event Name</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="event[title]" class="form-control" value="" required />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="day-start">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                <label class="form-label" for="event[all_day]">All day event?</label>
                <div>
                    <select class='form-control' name='event[all_day]' id='all_day' required>
                        <option value='0' selected>No</option>
                        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
                <label class="form-label" for="event[start_date]">Start</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="event[start_date]" class="dateclicker form-control" value="" placeholder='Date' required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-3 partial-day">
                <label class="form-label" for="event[start_time]">&nbsp;</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="event[start_time]" class="timeclicker form-control" value="" placeholder="Time" required/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row' id="day-end">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6"></div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-3 partial-day">
                <label class="form-label" for="event[end_date]">End</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="event[end_date]" class="dateclicker form-control" value="" placeholder='Date' required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-3 partial-day">
                <label class="form-label" for="event[end_time]">&nbsp;</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="event[end_time]" class="timeclicker form-control" value="" placeholder='Time' required />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <label class="form-label" for="event[color]">Pick a color</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="color-field" name="event[color]" required/>
        <div class='row' id='colors'>
            <!--Colors populate here via js-->
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class='row' id="notify-me">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                <label class="form-label" for="event[notify_bool]">Would you like to set an email notification for this event?</label>
                <div>
                    <select class='form-control' name='event[notify_bool]' id="notify-bool">
                        <option value='1' selected>Yes</option>
                        <option value='0'>No</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-5" id="notify-hours">
                <label class="form-label" for="event[notify_hours]">Notify me this many hours before the event</label>
                <div>
                    <input type="number" name="event[notify_hours]" class="form-control tickler-time" value="" min="0" placeholder='Hours'/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class='row'>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                <label class="form-label" for="event[notes]">Add a note for this event</label>
                <div>
                    <textarea name="event[notes]" id="notes"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#submit-form').click(function(){
$.post('notifications/add_event', 
    $('#event-form').serialize(), 
    function(data, status, xhr){
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
            {
                title: data.title,
                start: data.start,
                end: data.end
            },
            true        
        );
        $('#eventModal').modal('hide');
    });
```

});

Comment: I haven't used the jQuery validate plugin, but I suspect all it does is get each input field and verify its value against some rule you specify to the plugin. You can do the same thing by looping over all your input fields, and for each validating the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting the html5 validation to work as intended with the button outside of the form. You'd need to place hidden button inside of the form and have the visual button click the other button to force the html5 validation.

```js
var form = $('#event-form');
form.on('submit', function() {
  // do ajax request
});

$('#submit-form').on('click', function() {
    $('#real-submit').click();
})
```

```css
body .modal {
  position: relative;
  top: auto;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  left: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
}
body .modal-dialog {
  left: auto;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="modal" id="eventModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="eventModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="eventModalLabel">New Event</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="event-form">
          <div class='row'>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
              <label class="form-label" for="event[title]">Event Name</label>
              <div>
                <input type="text" name="event[title]" class="form-control" value="" required />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row" id="day-start">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
              <label class="form-label" for="event[all_day]">All day event?</label>
              <div>
                <select class='form-control' name='event[all_day]' id='all_day' required>
                  <option value='0' selected>No</option>
                  <option value='1'>Yes</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
              <label class="form-label" for="event[start_date]">Start</label>
              <div>
                <input type="text" name="event[start_date]" class="dateclicker form-control" value="" placeholder='Date' required />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-3 partial-day">
              <label class="form-label" for="event[start_time]">&nbsp;</label>
              <div>
                <input type="text" name="event[start_time]" class="timeclicker form-control" value="" placeholder="Time" required/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='row' id="day-end">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6"></div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-3 partial-day">
              <label class="form-label" for="event[end_date]">End</label>
              <div>
                <input type="text" name="event[end_date]" class="dateclicker form-control" value="" placeholder='Date' required />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-3 partial-day">
              <label class="form-label" for="event[end_time]">&nbsp;</label>
              <div>
                <input type="text" name="event[end_time]" class="timeclicker form-control" value="" placeholder='Time' required />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" id="real-submit" style="visibility: hidden" />
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" id="submit-form" class="btn btn-primary">Save Event</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While true, this doesn't answer the poster's question at all.

Comment: The problem with that is that I'm using bootstrap modals and the submit button is stuck in the footer of the modal outside the form. I could move it up into the body of the modal but then it wouldn't look pretty. ;~;

Comment: You could just bind an event on your button to then submit your form.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can validate your form before the ajax request. But you have to write down your own validations, checking all the input to be sure their value meet your requirements.

If you want validate the form after the submit button is pushed, you can do this:

```
$('your-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(): //this prevent the normal submit processed by the browser


    //your validation here

    //if everything is ok
    $.ajax({...})

});
```

If you want to validate the form before the submit button is pressed, then you can do it at the input blur/change, like this:

```
$('your-form input').each(function(e) {
    $(this).on('blur', function() {
        //your validation here
    });
});
```

In both cases you can trigger the submit keeping the submit button outside the form this way:

```
$('your-submit-button').on('click', function() {
    $('your-form').submit();
});
```

You don't need to create multiple buttons, just to trigger

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#event-form').on('submit', function(e){    
// do your validation code
// ...
// if all is ok
$.ajax(...)
 // else
e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: The problem is still that since I'm using bootstrap modals I'd have to move the submit button out of the footer and into the body to be part of the form. Then it wouldn't look pretty.

Comment: If you do e.preventDefault() prior to submit, it would never execute submit.

Comment: You are right, sory. It's my mistake. Not .submit(), we must do ajax request.

Comment: #Nyx Is The Best, try do this code $('#event-form').off('submit').on('submit', function...

Comment: @Anon: I changed the sequence of events in your answer to perform validation first and if it fails, invoke e.preventDefault().

Comment: @DinoMyte: we must do preventDefault before validation. Because if we do ajax with default form submit we obtain double form data on server side

Comment: @Anon: The fact that e.preventDefault() would not post the form, declaring it as a first statement would make it a dummy button. In order to use it with ajax, one should use input of type button , not button.