# How do I correct the error uncaught typeError validator is undefined and prevent my form from post if error

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, jquery-validate

Here is my situation.

Part 1: I press a link on my Index View.cshtml to pop my modal AddContact.cshtml (below) in debug mode jquery is throwing the following error "typeError Validator not defined" if I type anything into a textbox or try to use the dropdown.

[image]

[image]

Note my Index View has a layout _Layout.cshtml which have the script bundles:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

But, when I built my partial View AddContact.cshtml ... I don't use a layout _Layout.cshtml, is this why I am getting the typeError validator?

So, that I believe is the big question, How do I fix the typeError?

Part 2, Before I realize the error in Part 1, I added $.validate() to my javascript below It seems that my form $(#contactForm).validate() below,on my form is ALWAYS throwing a NOT Valid. What I would like to happen is the error message defined in my model would appear and the $.ajax() post would be prevented, if there are errors.

```
  $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        if ($("#contactForm1").validate()) {
            alert("Form is Valid");
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("Form is NOT Valid");
            return false;
        }

        var frm = $('#contactForm1').serialize()

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/AddContact/",
            data: frm,
            success: function (ajaxRespond) {
                if (ajaxRespond.dbUpdateResult == "success") {
                    $("#myModal").modal("hide");
                    reloadContactLinks()
                }
            }
        })

    })
```

I have a view model: set with Required Annotations

```
  public class Contact
    {
        public int Contact_ID { get; set; }
        public int Dataset_ID { get; set; }
        public string Booth_UCID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is a required field")]
        public string First_Name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is a required field")]
        public string Last_Name { get; set; }
        public string Title_Role { get; set; }
        public int Contact_Type_ID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is a required field")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone Number is a required field")]
        public string Phone_Number { get; set; }
        public string Email_2 { get; set; }
        public string Phone_Number_2 { get; set; }
    }
```

I have my partial View with JQuery Validate and Ajax Post

```
   @model ResearchDataInventoryWeb.Models.Contact
    @using (Html.BeginForm(new { id = "contactForm1" }))
    {
        <div class="section_header2">Contact</div>
        <div style="padding-top:5px;">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class="display-label">UCID/Booth ID</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Booth_UCID, new { placeholder = "<Booth/UCID>", @class = "input-box" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class="display-label">Type</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select class="input-box" id="contact_type">
                            <option value="contact_type">Contact Type*</option>
                            <option value="dataset_admin">Dataset Admin</option>
                            <option value="dataset_Provider">Dataset Provider</option>
                            <option value="department">Department</option>
                            <option value="external_collaborator">External Collaborator</option>
                            <option value="principal_investigator">Principal Investigator</option>
                            <option value="research_center">Research Center</option>
                            <option value="vendor">Vendor</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class="display-label">Name</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.First_Name, new { placeholder = "<First Name>", @class = "input-box-modal" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.First_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Last_Name, new { placeholder = "<Last Name>", @class = "input-box-modal" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Last_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class="display-label">Email</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { placeholder = "<Email 1>", @class = "input-box-modal" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email_2, new { placeholder = "<Email 2>", @class = "input-box-modal" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class="display-label">Phone</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone_Number, new { placeholder = "<Phone 1>", @class = "input-box-modal" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone_Number, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone_Number_2, new { placeholder = "<Phone 2>", @class = "input-box-modal" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class="display-label">Job Title</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title_Role, new { placeholder = "<Job Title>", @class = "input-box" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class="display-label">Organization</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="input-box" type="text" placeholder="<Organization>" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
    
            </table>
            <div style="padding-left:10px; margin-top:10px;">
                <textarea rows="3" placeholder="Notes"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="centerButton" style="margin-top: 30px;">
            <div style="margin-left:30px">
                <submit id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="padding:14px"><span class="smallText_red" style="padding:30px">SAVE</span></submit>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-left:30px">
                <submit class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="padding:14px"><span class="smallText_red" style="padding:30px">REMOVE</span></submit>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            if ($("#contactForm1").validate()) {
                alert("Form is Valid");
                return true;
            } else {
                alert("Form is NOT Valid");
                return false;
            }
    
            var frm = $('#contactForm1').serialize()
    
            $.ajax({
    
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/AddContact/",
                data: frm,
                success: function (ajaxRespond) {
                    if (ajaxRespond.dbUpdateResult == "success") {
                        $("#myModal").modal("hide");
                        reloadContactLinks()
                    }
                }
            })
    
        })
    
    </script>
```

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53513205/3825777 Can you try to make a runnable snippet like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/33681460/3825777 Or, a jsfiddle like this? http://jsfiddle.net/duAkn/ or this? http://jsfiddle.net/Vikrant29/jr346y1u/5/

Comment: Thank you for your response, but no neither of these are addressing my issues.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I don't know how to do the code snippet

Comment: `$(function(){ ... your code here ... });` will set your handlers on documentReady i.e. DOM model is built. Probably this generates the issue.

Comment: @Reflective I am not understanding how to use $(function() {... my code ...} does this mean wrap this around my $("btnSumbit).click(functio{() { }) which works or are you suggesting wrapping my code in $(document).ready(). Thank you though, this project has been full of starts and stops

Comment: ok, i've posted an answer to explain what I mean

Comment: @Reflective I posted a comment, in case you did not get it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work on the DOM it should be ready, so I'm suggesting you to change it that way and I hope it will help. If not, we should look for other issues.

EDIT!!! That is a very rough example and may have some issues, but that's the way you should use validator. The validator captures `onsubmit` form event, so no click handler is required and it's bat if you do it that way as I believe first click event is handled.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { 

  var validator = $("contactForm1").validate({
      submitHandler: function(form){
          $(form).find('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
          var frm =$(form).serialize()    
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "/Home/AddContact/",
              data: frm,
              success: function (ajaxRespond) {
                if (ajaxRespond.dbUpdateResult == "success") {
                    $("#myModal").modal("hide");
                    reloadContactLinks()
                }
              }
          })    
      }
  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: I did what you said, and $("#contactForm1).validate() is always false. If I take the $("#contactForm1).validate() out, the form runs the $.ajax no problem, but I don't want this is the form has errors, this is so frustrating because this works great except for the error checking any other suggestions. and really Thank you so much for trying, I didn't expect any responses

Comment: It's 3 o'clock AM at my time - I'll take a look tomorrow if there is still no proper answer

Comment: you should not use '.click` but use $("#contactForm1").validate() with params. there is an internal handler on successful submit

Comment: Wow, you work late. Thank you so much, and if I figure out anything i will be certain to let you know. I usually do figure these things out, but I am no expert by far. I have written a lot of systems but it is trial and error

Comment: I will try your suggestion

Comment: @Paul T. Rykiel I've edited my answer to show you haw to use the validator. It my have some issues as I've done it quickly, but generally that's the way.

Comment: you should also add your rules in HTML or specify them as options in validate ... if it's just `required` and you have an input you can add it like this `<input name="somename" value="somevalue" required>`. BTW modern browsers will also check this attribute (required) and will signal an error if field is not completed even w/o using the jquery validator, but here you have more options.

Comment: Thank you, I will try all of your suggestions and let you know. and really, Thank you for all of your help

Comment: Use console.log instead of alert to help debug and/or output variables.

Comment: @Reflective I did try your suggestion, still not working, closer but now it works randomly

Comment: @Reflective once again thank you for all of your help. I could not get jquery validate to work, so what I ended up doing is manually checking the dom elements to validate and returning true or false.I realize this is a lot extra work, but I am satisfied with the result. Jquery validate was unstable, it only worked randomly, but did not prevent the form from being submitted.